# Confused about Hamming window and its relation with frequency response specification

Tags: filters

$w(n)= 0.54 + 0.46\cos(2n \pi/(M-1))$ is Hamming window and we have say $f_{s_1}$,$f_{p_1}$,$f_{p_2}$,$f_{s_2}$ with pass and stopband tolerance specifications of the desired filter. From this specification can we get mathematical corresponding frequency response?

Comment: i think you need to be more explicit about what $f_{s_1}$ and the rest are.  i figure we're talking about stopband and passband frequencies.  why two sets of stopband and passband?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowing has nothing much to do with your filter design/response spec's, however, it has impact on your transition bandwidth that also depends on the window length.Your filters frequency response is mainly dependent on design parameters such as sampling rate, maximum frequency, transition bandwidth, cut-off frequency and impulse response length or kernel length.Now coming to windowing, these are some techniques basically used for obtaining smoother and ripple free impulse response h[n], so before your multiply your impulse response to the input/incoming samples, you must window your impulse response. For e.g. If you have a sinc impulse response, Ideally we know that its amplitudes run infinite on both negative and positive ends, hence in practice we just taper or cut off the ends of the sinc impulse in order to make it a finite length, therefore, this causes ripples in the impulse response due to the *Gibbs Phenomenon* (for more info on Gibbs Phenomenon, check online), So to eliminate these ripples and get a smoother impulse response, we use these windowing techniques.And each windows vary, for e.g. Blackman windows have better stopband attenuation than hamming window. Between why have you specified two stopband and passband frequencies?. Anyways,hope this gives you some insight to windowing!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can calculate the frequency response. Amplitude modulation is convolution in the frequency domain.The window is amplitude modification/smoothing and as such this works. So, all you need to do is convolve the frequency response with the frequency response of the Hamming window's function.